# Qt with OpenCv does nothing

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

I´m using Qt 5.0.2 and try to get started with OpenCv.

If I run the following program, it only shows a console and says press any key but it shows no image. I don´t even get the qDebug() messages.

However, with the Opencv stuff deleted I get the messages.

PS: yes I made sure that the Desert.jpg is in the same folder where the exe is. 
first-openCV-test.pro:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = first-openCV-test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += F:\\QT\\libraries\\opencv\\opnecv_build_2.4.5\\install\\include
LIBS += -LF:\\QT\libraries\\opencv\\opnecv_build_2.4.5\\install\\lib \
    -lopencv_core245.dll \
    -lopencv_highgui245.dll \
    -lopencv_imgproc245.dll \
    -lopencv_features2d245.dll \
    -lopencv_calib3d245.dll
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        // read an image
        qDebug()<< "start initialising";
        cv::Mat image= cv::imread("Desert.jpg");
        // create image window named "My Image"
        qDebug()<< "name Window";
        cv::namedWindow("My Image");
        // show the image on window
        qDebug()<< "show image: ";
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        // wait key for 5000 ms
        qDebug()<< "wait";
        cv::waitKey(5000);
        return 1;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

thanks for the fast answers.

I tried some things and also rebuilt  all and re-downloaded it. I changed it to this:
    QT       += core
    QT       -= gui
    TARGET = first-test
    CONFIG   += console
    CONFIG   -= app_bundle
    TEMPLATE = app
    SOURCES += main.cpp

```
INCLUDEPATH += "F:/QT/libraries/opencv/build/include" \
               "F:/QT/libraries/opencv/build/include/opencv" \
               "F:/QT/libraries/opencv/build/include/opencv2"

LIBS += -L"F:/QT/libraries/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib"
    -libopencv_core245.dll
    -libopencv_highgui245.dll
    -libopencv_imgproc245.dll
    -libopencv_features2d245.dll
    -libopencv_calib3d245.dll
```

But now I get the following errors:

F:\A_PROJECTS\OPEN-CV\first-test\first-test\main.cpp:-1: Fehler:undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'

F:\A_PROJECTS\OPEN-CV\first-test\first-test\main.cpp:-1: Fehler:undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'

Comment: thanks for the fast answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if this will help you, but lets give a try...

First, in my programs I use the bars '**/**' instead of '**\\**'. 
Second I never put .dll at libs. I use something like this:

`LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV/lib/ -llibopencv_core245 -llibopencv_highgui245 -llibopencv_imgproc245`

Try to do those changes and then 'run qmake' and 'rebuild all', if you are using the qtcreator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image was successfully loaded:

```
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("Desert.jpg");
if (image.empty())
{
    // print error message
    return -1;
}
```

I wrote a simple OpenCV/Qt sample project named [cvImage](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvImage) which demonstrates [how to configure a .pro](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/blob/master/cvImage/cvImage.pro) file to make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

An "undefined reference" error is thrown when the dependency (an external library like openCV)) is not linked to the Qt project correctly. I have answered a similar question that I know will solve your problem. Instead of altering the .pro file manually, you use the "Add Library..." wizard inside Qt Creator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51914801/10245006