# OpenCV, Qt, imread, namedWindow, imshow does not work

Tags: image, qt, opencv, imshow

In the `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET    = latihan_2
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += E:\OpenCV\OpenCV\opencv\build\include

LIBS += E:\OpenCV\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_core246.dll.a
LIBS += E:\OpenCV\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_highgui246.dll.a
LIBS += E:\OpenCV\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_imgproc246.dll.a
LIBS += E:\OpenCV\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_features2d246.dll.a
LIBS += E:\OpenCV\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\libopencv_calib3d246.dll.a
```

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(){
    //read image
    Mat image = imread("img.jpg", 1);
    //create image window named "My image"
    namedWindow("My Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //show the image on window
    imshow("My image", image);
    //wait key for 5000ms
    waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
    }
```

When I hit run, there is no error, but it only shows a black window named `qtcreator_process_stub.exe`.

Why the "My image" window doesn't come out and shows the img.jpg?
I use Qt creator 2.8.1, based on Qt 5.1.1, and openCV-2.4.6.0.

Comment: Are you sing pre-built binaries for OpenCV and Qt..?

Comment: yes, i use openCV 2.4.6

Comment: It seems like Qt is not being linked properly with OpenCV.. I would suggest you to build the libraries for both Qt and OpenCV yourself. The generation process will make sure that everything is linked properly.

Comment: @Squirrelcages Review all the answers and click on the checkbox near the answer that helped you solve the problem. You will be helping yourself and future visitors by doing this.

Answer (score 3):

**You could also display a `cv::Mat` on a Qt window.** I demonstrate how to do that on [**cvImage**](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvImage). The code below is adapted from `cvImage::_open()`:

```
std::string filename = ...
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(filename);

// Since OpenCV uses BGR order, we need to convert it to RGB
// NOTE: OpenCV 2.x uses CV_BGR2RGB, OpenCV 3.x uses cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

// image is created according to Mat dimensions
QImage image(mat.size().width, mat.size().height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

// Copy cv::Mat to QImage
memcpy(image.scanLine(0), mat.data, static_cast<size_t>(image.width() * image.height() * mat.channels()));

// Display the QImage in a QLabel
QLabel label;
label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
label.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

First guess is that the image is in the wrong path, so first test should be to specify the full path to the image.

Also check the return value of your program (make sure the it doesn't return some crash error code - be consistent and return 0 for success and other values for fail).

And a little bit of coding that tells you where the code fails doesn't hurt, so check image.data or you can also use [image.empty()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-empty):

```
if(! image.data )
{
    std::cout << "No image to display";
    //can be any other method to display the error: qDebug, a messagebox... 
    //you can also 
    return 1;   
}
else
{
    //use the image
    //if nothing goes wrong:
    //return 0; 
}
```

Comment: +1 I think `imshow()` would crash if the image was not loaded, but it's an important thing what you are pointing out.

Comment: i've tried the code, but there nothing changed.. still shows only window named qtcreator_process_stub.exe, with message "Press <RETURN> to close this window..."

Comment: If you use Qt Creator check the _Application Output_ for the return code of your application and the standard output messages (the cout message) are in there too if you use a gui application.

Comment: The Application output is :
E:\OpenCV\Projects\myQtConsoleProject\build-latihan_2-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\latihan_2.exe exited with code 0

Answer (score 0):

Check Projects->Run Settings ->Run in Terminal checkbox. If it is disabled, enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and I solved it by fixing path environment variable. In my path environment variable I added some opencv folders wrongly, then I deleted them and add only bin folder for opencv DLLs and then the problem was solved.