# Load an image in hard disk using OpenCV and Qt

Tags: image, qt, opencv, qstring, imread

I am new using Qt and OpenCV.
I am trying to read an image in my HD and show it.
It is not a specific image, the program could read any image that user select.
My code:

```
QString Imagename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                this,
                tr("Open Images"),
                "C://",
                tr("Tiff Files (*.tif);; Raw file (*.raw)"));

 if ( Imagename.isNull())
    {
         QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error!","Image not valid!");
    }


    cv::Mat src(filename);
```

Mat configuration is:
Mat imread(const string& filename, int flags=1 )

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

`cv::Mat` doesn't have a contructor that accepts a string. Use `imread` instead. Since `imread` accepts `std::string`, not `QString`, just do:

```
cv::Mat yourImage = cv::imread(filename.toStdString());
```

Comment: same error at:                                                          namedWindow("Original Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Original Image", srcimage);

Comment: @RenatoFeijo do you link against opencv_highgui[xxx]? And #include <opencv2\opencv.hpp> ?

Comment: yes. I link:  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Comment: @RenatoFeijo but seems a linking error, am I right? Are you linking to opencv_core[xxx], etc, and *opencv_highgui[xxx]*?

Comment: in PRO file, I use: INCLUDEPATH += \\C++\\opencv\\opencv\\build\\include
LIBS += -LC:\\C++\\opencv\\opencv\\build\x64\\vc12\\lib \
  -lopencv_highgui2410d \
  -lopencv_imgproc2410d \
  -lopencv_core2410d

Comment: Does the code compile and link without all imread, imshow code, but just with a Mat1b a(5,5,uchar(0)); ?

Comment: Also, have you Qt compiled with msvc12 or mingw?

Comment: problems occur with all imread, imshow, namedWindow. I am using mingw.

Comment: you are linking with libraries compiled with msvc.. that won't work! Either recompile opencv with mingw, or set Qt to use msvc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013903/opencv-on-qt-imread-namedwindow-imshow-does-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use cv::Mat variable as you used.To solve this problem you should use "imread" function.I think following code will help you about this issue. You have to include following libraries.

```
    #include<QFileDialog>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    int main (){
    // Gets file name with QFileDialog
    QString file_name=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open Image File","C://","Image File (*.jpg *.tiff *.png *.bmp)"); 

    // Read image with Color Image Parameter and store on image variable which type is cv::Mat
    // You should convert file name from QString to StdString to use in imread function
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(file_name.toStdString(),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 

   if(!image.data){   // Checks whether the image was read successfully 
      qDebug()<< "Could not open or find the image";  
      return -1;
                  }

    cv::namedWindow("Original Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Creates a window which will display image 
    cv::imshow("Original Image",image);     // Shows image on created window

    cv::waitKey(0);    // Waits for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;  // if you created console app in qt you should use return a.exec() instead of this.
}
```